# How to prove the integral comparison theorem?

Tags: calculus, integration

> Theorem : Let $f$ be non-increasing. Then $ \sum_{1}^{\infty} f(n) $ converges if and only if  $\int_{1}^{\infty} f(x) dx $ converges ?

The first line of the proof in my textbook is :

Let $ c_n= \int_{n}^{n+1} f(x) dx $, then, $$ \int_{1}^{k} f(x) dx = \sum_{n=1}^{k-1} \int_{n}^{n+1}f(x)dx. $$

I am struggling to understand this equality and where it is coming from as well as why it is helpful to prove this theorem.

Comment: P.S.: `\infty` Renders $\infty$ in TeX

Answer (score 1):

As $f$ is non-increasing we have
$$
f(n+1)=\int_n^{n+1}f(n+1)\,dx\leq\int_n^{n+1}f(x)\,dx\leq\int_n^{n+1} f(n)\,dx=f(n).
$$
Adding up from $n=1$ to $N-1$ we arrive at
$$
\sum_{n=2}^{N}f(n)\leq\int_1^{N}f(x)\,dx\leq\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}f(n),
$$
which tells us that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)=\infty\Longleftrightarrow\int_1^\infty f(x)dx=\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint. We have that 
$$[1,k]=[1,2]\cup[2,3]\cup\dots\cup[k-1,k]=\bigcup_{n=1}^{k-1}[n,n+1], $$
which implies 
$$\int_{1}^{k} f(x) dx=\int_{1}^{2} f(x) dx+\int_{2}^{3} f(x) dx
+\dots+\int_{k-1}^{k} f(x) dx=
\sum_{n=1}^{k-1} \int_{n}^{n+1}f(x)dx.$$
Moreover, since $f$ is non-increasing,
$$\sum_{n=1}^{k-1}f(n)=\sum_{n=1}^{k-1}\int_{n}^{n+1}f(n)dx \geq \sum_{n=1}^{k-1} \int_{n}^{n+1}f(x)dx\geq  \sum_{n=1}^{k-1} \int_{n}^{n+1}f(n+1)dx=\sum_{n=1}^{k-1}f(n+1).$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: I dont understand the second line, how the union implies the equality ?

Comment: @iheartalgebraa additivity property of integrals. See my edited answer. Is it clear now?

Comment: #iheartalgebraa Any further doubt?