# How to prove that $\sum_{k=1}^nf(k)>\int_1^nf(x)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, inequality, summation

Context: This is a question I thought of when seeing a generalization of Euler's constant on its Wikipedia page.

We have a function $f:\mathbb{R}\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ which decreases as its input increases and is always greater than zero. How do I prove that $$\sum_{k=1}^nf(k)>\int_1^nf(x)dx\tag{1}$$Where $f(x)$ is defined for all integer $x$ and $n$ is an integer?

I know that by the FTC, using $$\sum_{k=1}^nf(k)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty(f(k)-f(k+n))$$, and taking the derivative of both sides, we have that $(1)$ is equivalent to $$-\sum_{k=1}^\infty f'(k+n)>f(n)$$By the way, the LHS is positive since $f(n)$ is decreasing, meaning that $f'(n)$ is negative. But other than that I am stuck and don't know what to do.

Comment: See Apostol, T., Mathematical Analysis, 2nd edition,  Addiaon Weslesley, Theorem 8.23, pp. 191-192

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2063771/42969

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each $k$, $f(k)\ge f(t)$ for $t\in [k,k+1]$, because $f$ is decreasing, so
$$
\sum_{k=1}^nf(k) = \sum_{k=1}^n\int_{k}^{k+1}f(k)\,dt \ge \sum_{k=1}^n\int_{k}^{k+1}f(t)\,dt = \int_{1}^{n+1}f(t)\,dt.
$$
Equality holds if and only if $f$ is almost everywhere equal to the step function $\sum_{k=1}^\infty f(k)1_{[k,k+1]}(t)$.

Comment: Thank you for your intuitive response! +1